# Login with gmail not working in Ionic 3 for IOS

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular5

I am working on Hybrid Mobile Application in which I have implemented a Google Plus Plugin. It is successfully working on Android but not IOS. For IOS, it open the dialog box, after putting username and password it is redirected to google.com instead of returning back to application.

I have done a login with Gmail and Firebase. I have put the web client id from firebase and reversed client id from `GooglService-Info.plist`.
I have searched on Google, some says use:

```
"cordova-plugin-googleplus": "5.2.1" and  "@ionic-native/google-plus": "4.20.0"
```

Currently, I use:

```
"cordova-plugin-googleplus": "7.0.0" and  "@ionic-native/google-plus": "4.17.0"
```

in the application.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try installing from this repo it worked for me,
don't forget to `ionic cordova platform rm ios` and removing the old `cordova-plugin-googleplus` before installing this, also don't forget to add your `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID`
`https://github.com/pcsantana/cordova-plugin-googleplus`

after install you add the iOS platform back `ionic cordova platform add ios` and voila